# devexpress wpf gridcontrol disable context menu

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a **DevExpress grid control** and I want to disable the default context menu that appears when I right click the Grid column headers. To disable this functionality I handled the `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` and `PreviewMouseRightButtonUp`

```
private void UserControl_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown_Up(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

This is not an acceptable solution. There should be should be something on grid control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please set the [TableView.IsColumnMenuEnabled](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_IsColumnMenuEnabledtopic) property to control whether the column context menu is shown when an end-user right-clicks a column's header.
You can read more about all avilable DXGrid's context menus and its customization here: [Context Menus](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6587)

Answer (score 1):

Set IsColumnMenuEnabled="False" on your TableView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want disable specific context menu item you can manage it by binding

```
 <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="contexMenuTransmitPendingClaim"
                                                       Command="{Binding Path=(dxb:GridPopupMenuBase.GridMenuInfo).View.DataContext.TransmitPendingClaimCommand,
                                                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                                       Content="Transmit Pending Claim"
                                                       IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(dxb:GridPopupMenuBase.GridMenuInfo).View.DataContext.SelectedCusHisViewRefillHistory.IsPendingClaimsActive,
                                                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                                           Mode=TwoWay,
                                                                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```